# In Swift, How do I make the highlighted rows to remain highlighted after reloading a table?

Tags: swift, styles, tableview

After a row is being deleted in a simple to-do list, how do I make the already highlighted rows to remain highlighted? Currently the rows that have background colors become plain (lose background color) after table is re-loaded. This app is made using `Swift`. Below is the function that's causing the problem.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
    toDoList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row) 
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(toDoList, forKey: "toDoList")
    toDoListTable.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Comment: If there a reason you need to do `reloadData()` instead of doing `tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)`?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I'm new to Swift and iOS development, but I'll try that now. I've just been modifying an existing code and got stuck here. @Kevin